# "backendError" when migrating Google marketplace App from v1 to v2 using UpgradeableApp API

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

We're trying to migrate an app from v1 (using openid) to v2 (Oauth 2.0) in the Google Apps Marketplace.

The old app is published in the old marketplace.
The new app is published in the Chrome Webstore.
We have associated the new app to the old app, using the webstore App id.
As a result, the install button in the old marketplace now says "Install App" (as opposed to the old "Add it now"). It works fine.

However we're also trying to migrate existing domains from the old app to the new app.

We are using the UpgradeableApp API, using an HTTP PUT request to this URL:

https://www.googleapis.com/appsmarket/v2/upgradableApp/1234%3A1234512345/somelongappid/sampledomain.com

note we url-encoded the : in the old listing id with %3A, but even leaving the : the result is the same.

And signing it using 2-legged OAuth, using client Id and client secret of the old app, calculating and the adding the "Authorization" header to the request.

When we send the request, however, this is what we get back:

{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"backendError","message":"Backend Error"}],"code":500,"message":"Backend Error"}}

with an HTTP status code 500 (internal server error).

This does not seem to be an authentication error message, but it is not very clear what is causing the error... Something wrong on our side? Something temporarily wrong on Google's side (that is what I would assume, from "Backend Error")?

Has anyone encountered this cryptic error message before, while using this API?

We can provide a full network trace (with the real listing id, app id and domain names) as a private message, if necessary.